# ClassNotFoundException mac applet issue

Tags: java, html, ios, applet

I embedded a simple applet in a html website. When I try to open it on my mac, I get the error message: ClassNotFoundException.
All other parts of the html page are displayed except the applet. 
I cannot decide whether this is some security issue (though I enabled everything I could in Java Control Panel) or I give a wrong Codebase (though I tried various possibilities for hours)
Answers to previous questions dont seem to help.
Any hint is appreciated.
Thanks!

My html code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
             <title>Applet-Beispiel</title>
         </head>
         <body>
             <h1>Applet-Beispiel</h1>
            Hier kann ganz normaler Text stehen. Zum Beispiel:
            <p>
            Hier sehen Sie ein sensationelles Applet.
            <p>
            <applet code="Appletek/bin/ClickCounter.class"
                codebase="./workspace/"
                width="150" height="50">
            </applet>
            <p>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) To have ***any chance*** of being launched in a modern JRE, an applet needs to be in a Jar and digitally signed. 3) *"I embedded a simple applet.."* Applets never were simple, and with recent security updates, became an order of magnitude more difficult.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did not know it was not supported any more.